# passing record type in procedure in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, records

```
declare
  type rec_1 is record(
     e_nm varchar2(10),
     e_no number );
  r1 rec_1; 
  --select EMPNO, ename  into r1 from emp where empno = 7369;
  procedure proc_t1(r1 rec1) as
  begin
    select EMPNO, ename  
      into r1.e_no, r1.e_nm 
      from emp 
     where empno = 7369;
     dbms_output.put_line(r1.e_nm);
   end;
```

I am getting syntax error after writing this code. Can any one pls tell me why this syntax error is coming?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL4N7.png)

Comment: A) Type's name is `rec_1` not `rec1` (formal parameter declaration). B) If you are going to select into the `r1` variable then you should declare it as `OUT` or `IN OUT` parameter. Now it's declared as `IN` parameter by default, which you cannot modify inside of your procedure. C). Main `begin...end` block is missing. D). **Always** post error messages.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, begin ... end block is present i guess. Just after the procedure  declaration

Comment: No it isn't. There's no `begin` for the `declare`, you just declare a type, a variable and a local procedure and then stop before doing anything with them.

Comment: I would really appreciate if the comments can be a bit elaborated on what else to be added. Really not getting being new to plsql

Comment: You need to close off both `declare...end` and the `procedure...end` blocks. You start two and finish one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what the code is meant to do, but perhaps you meant something like this:

```
declare
    procedure proc_t1
    is
        type emp_rectype is record
            ( id   emp.empno%type
            , name emp.ename%type );

        l_emp emp_rectype;
    begin
        select empno, ename into l_emp.id, l_emp.name
        from   emp
        where  empno = 7369;

        dbms_output.put_line(l_emp.name);
    end;

begin
    proc_t1();
end;
```

Notes:

1. There is no point declaring a record type outside the procedure unless you intend to reuse it elsewhere, which you don't in this example. If you want to reuse it, move it above the procedure declaration.
2. Procedure parameters default to `IN` mode, which is read-only, so in your example your `select into` would fail. It doesn't make sense to overwrite a parameter that was passed in, unless you want to transform it and pass it back out as a result.